# JQuery change class on hover button ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, button, hover

I'm new to JQuery. 
I have a button with a css-class that is working fine, but I want to change the css-class when I hover the button.

How do I code this?

This is what I got so far:

```
//on top in my heading:

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('btn').hover(function () {
        alert("Test"); //just for testing
    });
</script>

//my button:

<button id="btn" class="default_btn">ButtonText</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change reference to `#btn`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn').hover(function () {
            alert("Test"); //just for testing
        });

});
```

See JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/CKXw3/1/

Comment: I missed the "#" before my button-id and forgot the (document).ready-part at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you try CSS?

```
.default_btn:hover{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/Ytkma/

If you want jQuery Solution, try this.

```
$("#btn").hover(function() {
        $(this)
            .removeClass("default_btn")
            .addClass("default_hover_btn");
    }, function() {
        $(this)
            .removeClass("default_hover_btn")
            .addClass("default_btn");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/SfGVD/

Comment: I know how to do it in CSS, but trying to learn JQuery and want to try to do it with that =)

Comment: You could use the [toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) method for the class

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, for your code to work, change your selector to

```
$('#btn')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select ID's in jQuery you simply to it as you do in css: #id, in your case #btn

The jQuery helper function [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) normally needs to callbacks. one on mouse over and one on mouse out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').hover(function(){
        alert("over");
    },function(){
        alert("out");
    });
});
```

Another way is to detect the event type:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').hover(function(event){
        if (event.type == "mouseenter") {
            console.log("over");
        } else {
            console.log("out");
        }
    });
});
```

The function hover binds to functions to the jQuery Object. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Therefore we can assume if its not `mouseenter` it's `mouseleave`.